# What axioms do we need to exhibit a disjoint set of same size?

Tags: set-theory

Consider

**Lemma.** Let $A$ be a set. Then there exists a set $B$ such that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint and a bijective function $A\to B$.

*Remark:* In order to minimize the axioms needed to even speek of function graphs, the function shall be given by a formula $\phi(x,y)$ with the obvious properties $\forall a\in A\exists !b\in B\colon \phi(a,b)$ and $\forall b\in B\exists !a\in A\colon \phi(a,b)$. I'd prefer to avoid it, but in some cases it may be helpful to additionally equip $\phi$ with a parameter.

*Background:* This lemma is often useful when constructing an extension of some kind of a set (e.g., $\Bbb Z$ from $\Bbb N$ as a set of equivalence classes of pairs, or $\Bbb R$ from $\Bbb Q$ as Dedekind cuts) and for formal reasons one wants to have the original set (instead of an isomorphic image) actually as s subset of the extension.

---

A typical way to show the lemma would be to let $B=\{\,\{a,\{A\}\}\mid a\in A\,\}$ and the bijection of course $a\mapsto \{a,\{A\}\}$, here expressed as  (avoiding the use of $A$ as a parameter)
$$\phi(a,b)\equiv \exists c\colon b=\{a,\{c\}\}.$$ The construction of $B$ uses **Pair** and **Replacement**, the proof of disjointness uses **Foundation**, and I guess that the proof of bijectivity of the map does not need more than these (or probably "unconciously" **Extensionality** somewhere in the background).

**Question:** Which other minimal subsets of the usual ZFC axioms (counting axiom schemas as one) can be used to show the lemma? E.g., can we get rid of **Foundation** by using **Powerset**? While $P(A)$ is big enough to contain a suitable $B$, too much additional machinery may be needed to show the existence or explicitly come up with a $\phi$ or show its validity. Also of interest: Is there such a minimal set with **Choice** in it (in which case you may want to add a choice function as parameter to $\phi$)?

Comment: You can definitely get rid of foundation with the sum axiom (instead of $A$ as a second variable, you can pick $x$ such that $x\notin \bigcup\bigcup A$ and then $\{(a,x)\mid a\in A\}$ works with $(c,d)= \{\{c\}, \{c,d\}\}$)

Comment: @Max Good point. Plus, in order to express $x\notin \bigcup\bigcup A$, we do not even need **Union**, and the existence of such $x$ follows already from the existence of an ordinal with this property

Comment: I don't follow how you can prove that such an $x$ exists without Union (of course if you assume such an ordinal exists then yes, but how do you prove that such an ordinal exists ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be a set.

I want $B$ to be of the form $\{\{a,b\}:a\in A\}$ for some fixed $b$. To have $B$ be disjoint from $A$, it must be the case that $\{a,b\}\notin A$ for every $a\in A$. One way to satisfy this would be to have $b\notin\bigcup A$. That is to say, with the axiom of **union** and **separation** we can define $b:=\{x\in\bigcup A:x\notin x\}$. However, I will choose a $b$ so that $b$ additionally satisfies $b\notin A$. This can be done by defining $b$ to be instead $\{x\in (\bigcup A)\cup A:x\notin x\}$, where $S\cup T:=\bigcup\{S,T\}$ thereby officially using the axiom of **pairing** which would've been required at some point given how I want $B$ to be defined.

I want to find a desired bijective formula. Define the formula $\varphi$ with free variables $x$ and $y$ by

$$\begin{align}
\varphi(x,y):=(y=\{x,b\})
\end{align}$$

By the axiom of **extensionality**, $\varphi$ is function-like. Additionally, if $\{a_0,b\}=\{a_1,b\}$ for some $a_0,a_1\in A$, then because $b\notin A$ it follows that $a_0=a_1$. Therefore $\varphi$ is injective-like when defined on $A$.

The last step would be to construct $B$. One easy way would be to invoke replacement, but I have a preference towards the powerset/separation combo axioms. Define

$$B:=\{p\in\mathscr{P}(A\cup\{b\}):(\exists a\in A)(\exists \hat{b}\in\{b\})[p=\{a,\hat{b}\}]\}$$
thereby officially using the axiom of **power set**.